# Pytorch model gets no gradients updates (All gradients are Zero!)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, tensorboard

**Problem:**

- When training a torch network, all gradietns historgram using tensorboard are equal to zero. [TensorBoard Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNQmn.png)
- The loss function remains constant ~10.24

**Code Snippet**
The flow of the training is as follows:

```
TrOCR_model = TrOCR().to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(TrOCR_model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    batch_index = 0
    for images_batch, text_batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        images_batch = images_batch.to(device)
        output_probabilities, output_ids, output_text, target_ids, one_hot_encoded_output = TrOCR_model(images_batch, text_batch)            
        loss = criterion(output_probabilities, target_ids)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()
        batch_index += 1
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct to have: optimizer.zero_grad() -> Model(data) -> loss = criterion(output_probabilities, target_ids) -> loss.backward() -> optimizer.step()
2. The loss function produces a loss of around 10.25 and remainds constant, so there should be networks gradients, right?
3. (**Important**) Should I manually set in each initialization of tensors 'requires_grad=True'?

I tried the following:

1. The minimum number of layers (Simplified Model).
2. Proper initialization.
3. Larger learning rate in case gradients vanish so it helps to have higher learning rates.

still loss constant and zero gradients.

Comment: You always need to include a reproducible example, this is too little code to check for problems.

Comment: Why do you accumulate the loss in a (total) sum? Which one is constant `loss` or `total_loss`?

Comment: `model.train()` is generally enough to manually enable gradients on your weights.